# Java generic question mark and inheritance

Tags: java, generics

The four methods:

```
public Class<?> Func(Class<?> cls)  //1
public Class<?> Func(Class cls)  //2
public Class Func(Class<?> cls)  //3
public Class Func(Class cls)  //4
```

**I found that:**

1) 4 can override 3
2) 3 can't override 4.
3) But 2 and 4 can override each other.

Why?

This is may not about type conversion, since Class and Class<> can be converted to each other. This is more about why the compiler prevent (2) but allows (1) and (3).

Comment: quite unclear, can you share what have you tried for this override?

Comment: You shouldn't write 2, 3 and 4 in new code, however. They're using a raw type, [which should **not** be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Comment: @Vinay Prajapati I'm just building the code to find out the usage of question mark during inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Reasons - 
1 - `Class` means, any kind of `Class` object, i.e `Class<?>`.
2 - Function having `Class<?>` parameter cannot edit the object of `Class<?>` type, but a function having `Class` parameter can.

for example -

```
// function 1
void m(List<?> list){
    list.add(3);
}
// function 2
void m(List<?> list){
    list.get(0);
}
```

function 1 would not compile because it has a parameter `List<?>`, which means any list can be sent as parameter, but it cannot be editted, because one might send a `List<String>` and try to add an `Integer` to that list.

3 - A method can be overriden if the return type is the same or a subtype, and `Class<?>` and `Class` are same as return types as they both are returning Class objects, and any `Class` object can be typecasted to `Class<?>` or vice-versa

Comment: Does Class means Class<Object>? I think Class is more close to Class<?>. You can check out that "public Class Func(Class<Object> cls)" can't override any of them.

Comment: @jw_ yes I that makes sense, as `Class<Object>` would only except `Class<Object>` but `Class<?>` can except any kind of `Class` object